# Can you quote variable identifiers and parameter identifiers in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to quote variable and parameter identifiers in TSQL. The documentation appears to suggest that it is possible. However an error is thrown when executing variable names in quotes.

```
-- This works fine, as one would expect
DECLARE @ExampleVariableGood bigint

-- Error - "can" variable names be quoted identifiers?
DECLARE [@ExampleVariableBad] bigint
```

When executing script the following error is thrown:

```
Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Line 5
'bigint' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
```

The documentation states, variable identifiers must follow the same rules as for all identifiers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

This is an odd request, the only reason we need this to work is a SQL Studio tool auto formatting bug incorrectly quotes variable names, something the client does not want to change!

Comment: I don't understand the question here. Obviously the syntax you posted is invalid. And no idea why you would try that.

Comment: It's legal, but it doesn't do what you want -- in the statement above, `[@ExampleVariable]` is necessarily interpreted as a cursor name because the `@` isn't parsed as the sigil for a parameter/variable. This is only useful if you actually have a need to refer to things other than parameters and variables that contain `@` in their names. So if you *actually* have parameters/variables, this isn't going to work, and you'll have to use a non-broken tool that actually knows about T-SQL.

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers) do not state this in so many words -- they say that "a regular identifier that starts with the at sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used as the name of any other type of object", but they do not make clear that a delimited identifier cannot ever refer to a variable or parameter. Nevertheless, that is the case -- `select * from [@a]`, with `@a` a table variable or parameter is invalid; `select * from [#a]`, with `#a` a temp table, is not.

Comment: `select * from [@a]` would refer to a regular table. Called `@a` - not a table variable called `@a`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any quotes are taken from [Database Identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-2017#classes-of-identifiers)

Variables follow the rules for "regular identifiers". These are classed as:

> Regular identifiers
>   Comply with the rules for the format of identifiers. Regular identifiers are not delimited when they are used in Transact-SQL statements.

An object that is quoted (wraped in brackets (`[]`)), is not a regular identifier but a delimited identifier:

> Delimited identifiers
>   Are enclosed in double quotation marks (") or brackets ([ ]). Identifiers that comply with the rules for the format of identifiers might not be delimited. For example:

The fact that a variable follows the rules for a regular Identifier can be found in the Rules for Regular Identifiers section:

> The names of variables, functions, and stored procedures must comply
>   with the following rules for Transact-SQL identifiers.
>
> 1. The first character must be one of the following:
>
>    - A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from
>        A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
>    - The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).
>
>      Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL Server. A regular identifier that starts with the at
>        sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used
>        as the name of any other type of object. An identifier that starts
>        with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure. An
>        identifier that starts with double number signs (##) denotes a global
>        temporary object. Although the number sign or double number sign
>        characters can be used to begin the names of other types of objects,
>        we do not recommend this practice.
>
>      Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not
>        use names that start with @@.

Therefore, as a variable's name must be a regular identifier, the **delimited** identifier `[@ExampleVariable]` is not a valid name.

*Although, oddly, you can make an SP/function that has a delimited identifier, which infers the documentation is out of date.*

Comment: I think the docs mess up because they confuse the actual name of something with the way we refer to it (or at least they don't make the distinction clear enough). That is, the table named `#a` can legally be referred to as either `#a` or `[#a]`, with one a regular identifier and the other a delimited one, but the variable named `@a` cannot legally be referred to as `[@a]`. `[@a]` *is* a valid identifier (`create table [@a]` works just fine!) but it can only ever refer to objects and never to variables. If the docs were unambiguous, we'd infer the same rules for `#a`, but that's not the case.

Comment: Jeroen thanks so much for your assistance. I read the same "misleading" documentation. The use of examples with @ are for delimited identifiers which I presume variables are not.